# Looking for book or tutorials for implementing face detection in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

I am Looking for book or tutorials for implementing face detection in iphone sdk? OpenCV is one but it takes more time to detect faces.

I want to learn algorithms used for face detection. Once i got a logic then it can be easily converted into programs.

Plz send me appropriate tutorials or ebook links ???

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298243/face-recognition-logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenCVS library [can be used on the IPhone](http://lambdajive.wordpress.com/2008/12/20/cross-compiling-for-iphone/):

[Learning OpenCV: Computer Vision with the OpenCV Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516134)

Comment: Did anyone try this for an iOS app ?