# Face detection on iPhone

Tags: iphone, sdk

What library can I use to enable face detection on iPhone? I just need detection, not recognition.
Is there something else than OpenCV?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for book or tutorials for implementing face detection in iphone sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829972/looking-for-book-or-tutorials-for-implementing-face-detection-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

This project might be helpful

https://github.com/beetlebugorg/PictureMe